# why doesn't looping smil animation in svg work as expected

Tags: svg, smil

I perform smil animation where I want fill to loop between two values ; this is what I use to

```
<polygon points="500,519 512.5,540 537.5,540 550,519 537.5,498 512.5,498" class="hex" id="259">
   <animate attributeName="fill" values="#080808;#82A1FF;080808" dur="4s" fill="freeze" begin="0" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
</polygon>
```

It does loop but seem it stuck on fill#82A1FF for the most of the 4 seconds ,it only slighly appears to move towards fill #080808 but rolls back to fill#82A1FF again.

I want the animation to be more uniform ,like a blinking light.

But now it looks like it is easing too much.

Comment: You're missing a `#` before the second `080808`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: No it take that number as Hex even without #, I figured it out ,its the way interpollation work in smil animate , have to change to the calcMethod to change as I want but then I loose gradient change